# How does SE decide to count user visits?

Tags: support

I have noticed there is a clear anomaly in how the site counts whether or not you've "visited" in a given day, as displayed on profiles in the visited xx days, xx consecutive part.  Some days that I visit the site it doesn't include it in the count.  Lately I've noticed a calender that shows specifically what days you did and didn't visit - and sure enough - there are recent days I went to the Physics SE bookmark and it didn't register.

I've tried this on other SE sites.  I made a bookmark folder that had SE sites for several accounts, and even though I'll visit them all, they will all read "1 consecutive" the next day.  However, if I click through several things and do several things, it registers the activity.  I do not know what it requires in order to count it or not count it and I'd like to find out.

I imagine some people hoping for the gold badge for 100 days visiting might be sourly surprised by site behavior on this account.

Comment: There has been [much discussion of these issues on the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consecutive-days), the most important fact is that "days" are measured between [midnights ***UTC***.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start/27201#27201) I've never had any trouble getting the consecutive days badges.

Answer (score 4):

- homepage visits are not counted toward this, you must visit an "interior" page
- our day is UTC 00:00:00 to UTC 23:59:59